# How to make printable reports (several charts) with Angular or Django

Tags: angular, matplotlib, highcharts, django-rest-framework, report

Sorry for the horrible title but I'm not sure how to word the issue properly.
I have an Angular 8 app that is communicating with a Django REST backend. The apps main function is to serve as a user friendly data entry point. It also crunches the data in the backend and spits it out through the API in a format that allows me to use said data with the Angular Highcharts wrapper and render several bar/pie/histogram/dist charts.

I would like to implement a feature to the frontend that allows me to somehow create a printable format (pdf, word, juypter notebook? Doesn't matter) with more than one of these charts and maybe others not directly visible in the frontend app. I envision this as the user clicking some sort of a "Print report" button, and generating a pdf printable preview.

I have absolutely no idea how I would go about doing this and would appreciate someone to point me in the right direction. I have fair understanding of how to use matplotlib, seaborn and pandas in case that the solution could require my backend to produce this printable output (I know how to recreate all the charts from Highcharts in Seaborn/Matplotlib) so it is not necessary for the printable output to be generated from Highcharts or from the frontend at all.

Comment: Did you tried something?? Here you have some info to print charts with Highcharts https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: Also if you want to export multiple charts in one PDF here you have the solution https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40382 , there's a clear example on how to make it.

Comment: I had investigated this method already and the problem is that it only allows printing one chart at a time. I wish to generate a complete report with various charts showing various relevant metrics

Comment: The second link is interesting, thank you. The main challenge is to possibly have to mix in reports not previously generated on the webapp

Comment: Hi @Jose Rafael Angulo, Highcharts allows to export only one chart by default. If you want to export multiple charts, you need to implement some custom solution, like from the forum link.